# boost regex sub-string match

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I want to return output "match" if the pattern "regular" is a sub-string of variable st.  Is this possible?

```
int main()
{
  string st = "some regular expressions are Regxyzr";

  boost::regex ex("[Rr]egular");
  if (boost::regex_match(st, ex)) 
  {
    cout << "match" << endl;
  }
  else 
  {
    cout << "not match" << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If so, what happened?

Comment: yes, I get "not match"
if st = "regular" I get "match"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The boost::regex_match only matches the whole string, you probably want boost::regex_search instead.

Answer (score 7):

[regex_search](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_search.html) does what you want; [regex_match](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) is documented as

> determines whether a given regular
>   expression matches **all** of a given
>   character sequence

(the emphasis is in the original URL I'm quoting from).

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered with example in library documentation - [boost::regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html)

Alternate approach:

You can use boost::regex_iterator, this is useful for parsing file etc.

```
string[0], 
string[1]
```

below indicates start and end iterator.

Ex:

```
boost::regex_iterator stIter(string[0], string[end], regExpression)
boost::regex_iterator endIter

for (stIter; stIter != endIter; ++stIter)
{
   cout << " Whole string " << (*stIter)[0] << endl;
   cout << " First sub-group " << (*stIter)[1] << endl;
}
```

}

Comment: The accepted answer on this page better explains sregex_iterator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593288/how-to-use-c-boosts-regex-iterator