# Boost regex and confusing errors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-regex

I'm trying to use Boost regex to see if something has an integer in it.

One of the examples on [this page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/introduction_and_overview.html) is

```
bool validate_card_format(const std::string& s)
{
   static const boost::regex e("(\\d{4}[- ]){3}\\d{4}");
   return regex_match(s, e);
}
```

There's also a presumably working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2061885/boost-regex-sub-string-match).

But when I try it on my machine, I get five pages of unreadable errors. What's going on?

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    static const boost::regex rxInt("[0-9]+");
    string word = "foobar";

    if(boost::regex_match(word, rxInt)) {
        cout << "Integer" << endl;
    } else {
        cout << "Not integer" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Errors for $g++ test.cpp. Is there some sane way to grok what is going on here?

```
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11regex_matchIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS5_EEEcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEbT_SD_RNS_13match_resultsISD_T0_EERKNS_11basic_regexIT1_T2_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsE[bool boost::regex_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)]+0x82): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match()'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost11basic_regexIcNS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE6assignEPKcS7_j[boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)]+0x2e): undefined reference to `boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEC1ES6_S6_RNS_13match_resultsIS6_S9_EERKNS_11basic_regexIcSD_EENS_15regex_constants12_match_flagsES6_[boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::perl_matcher(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >&, boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)]+0x103): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::construct_init(boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE18unwind_extra_blockEb[boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool)]+0x69): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_match()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE11match_matchEv[boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_match()]+0x16d): undefined reference to `boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > >::maybe_assign(boost::match_results<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > > > const&)'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `void boost::re_detail::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail11raise_errorINS_20regex_traits_wrapperINS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEEEEEvRKT_NS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[void boost::re_detail::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type)]+0x70): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack()':
test.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost9re_detail12perl_matcherIN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPKcSsEESaINS_9sub_matchIS6_EEENS_12regex_traitsIcNS_16cpp_regex_traitsIcEEEEE12extend_stackEv[boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<boost::sub_match<__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char const*, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack()]+0x36): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE9transformEPKcS3_[boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost16cpp_regex_traitsIcE17transform_primaryEPKcS3_[boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const]+0x38): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const'
/tmp/ccRNnDit.o: In function `boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const':
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0xa6): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
test.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost9re_detail31cpp_regex_traits_implementationIcE12error_stringENS_15regex_constants10error_typeE[boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const]+0x127): undefined reference to `boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Edit: I thought boost was all templated and only needed to be included. I've since tried compiling using "g++ test.cpp -L/usr/lib -llibboost_regex-mt" based on this:

```
$ ldconfig -p|grep libboost_regex
    libboost_regex-mt.so.1.38.0 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so.1.38.0
    libboost_regex-mt.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/libboost_regex-mt.so
```

But I get "/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibboost_regex-mt"

Comment: Are you using the same version of boost that the sample goes with - 1.42.0?

Comment: That might be it? I've got 1.38.1.

Comment: `g++ test.cpp -Lboost-lib-path -lboost_regex-gcc-mt` ?

Comment: I've just tried it with VS2010 it worked once I remembered to add the include and lib paths to the project so I think @S.Mark is likely to have the right answer

Comment: OK, try `g++ -v test.cpp -Lboost-lib-path -lboost_regex-gcc-mt`. You will get lots of information and also will see what arguments ld gets.

Comment: James, `-lboost_regex-mt`!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you link it, put `-l` and put appropriate boost lib name there.

In this case, the correct library name is 'boost_regex-mt'.

Answer (score 1):

The underlying errors are actually as follows:

```
undefined reference to boost::re_detail::perl_matcher
undefined reference to boost::match_results
undefined reference to boost::re_detail::get_mem_block
```

Answer (score 0):

Not all system have the -mt version, -lboost_regex works on Ubuntu, I assume it is built MT safe by default.