# How to use C++ Boost's regex_iterator()

Tags: c++, regex, boost, iterator

I am using Boost to match substrings in a string. Io iterate over the results, I need to use [`regex_iterator()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_iterator.html).

That is the only usage example I have found, but I do not understand the callback. Could someone give me an example uage of the function?

---

Let us assume that my input text is:

```
"Hello everybody this is a sentense
Bla bla 14 .. yes 
date 04/15/1986 
"
```

I want to get:

```
"Hello" "everybody" "this" "is" "a" "sentense" "bla" "yes" "date"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the only part of the example you don't understand is the callback, consider that:

```
std::for_each(m1, m2, &regex_callback);
```

is roughly equivalent to:

```
for (; m1 != m2; ++m1){
    class_index[(*m1)[5].str() + (*m1)[6].str()] = (*m1).position(5);
}
```

Assuming that, in your case, you want to store all the matches in a vector, you would write something like:

```
//Warning, untested:
boost::sregex_iterator m1(text.begin(), text.end(), expression);
boost::sregex_iterator m2;
std::vector<std::string> tokens;
for (; m1 != m2; ++m1){
    tokens.push_back(m1->str()).
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your explanation You may use tokenizer function.
And put some more logic into it.
look at [boost::tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html)

ex:

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep_1(" ");


std::string msg_copy ("Hello everybody this is a sentense Bla bla 14 .. yes date 04/15/1986 ");
boost::tokenizer< boost::char_separator<char> > tokens(msg_copy, sep_1);
BOOST_FOREACH(std::string t, tokens)
{
        // here you itterate t
}
```

edit:

You can put as many special characters to separator as you want ex:

```
boost::char_separator<char> sep_1(" *^&%~/|");
```

Comment: Yes this is a possible solution, but i forgot to mention that the text i realy want to fetch contains words separated by anything spaces, comas, dashs, pipe .. the best is to use regular expressions..
boost is the best for C++.
I have tried using Boost::regex_search() but it only returns the first match..
i need to get all matches.. for that i was told to use boost::regex_iterator() but i don't understand anything Boost's documentation realy sucks...

Comment: then use:
boost::char_separator<char> sep_1(" *^&%~/|");

It will tokenize against all of special chars ;)
Post updated as well