# Regular expression with a small bug

Tags: c++, regex, boost-regex

I have this string

```
hey {Bobby|Apple|Peter}, nice to meet you {David}
```

and this regex:

```
(\{(\w+)(\|(\w+))*)\}
```

the answer:

```
Bobby
Peter
David
```

However, it's not getting "Apple", how can I fix this to get it as well?

Thanks!

Comment: This homework? Should david have a capital letter?

Comment: Not homework... yes, editing right now.

Comment: K, then I'll answer, I'll try to find `find` within boost :)

Comment: Why the "nsregularexpression" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repetition does not work for groups. Instead, try to iteratively use find on the string. Probably best to first filter out `{Bobby|Apple|Peter}`, get the names from that, then find `{David}` and get the names from that. So that would be two finds, if you keep using regular expressions. Or one `find`, then a split on `|` from the result.

Regexp for the find: `\{(\w+(?:\|\w+)*)\}`, then use group 1 (everything *within* the braces) and split the result.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with boost::regex, but I dont think they have the filter out/find functions.

Comment: "filter out" whas just a human term for finding stuff and extracting the data from what you just found. Try to find some samples to iterate through matches within a string, something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593288/how-to-use-c-boosts-regex-iterator)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the entire, minimal code that reproduces this problem? It's possible the problem is with how you're iterating through the captured groups.

Comment: Doesn't matter much HywC, a group will only contain the last match.